# How to add search option to Android Spinner?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a long list of data display in android spinner. So i want to add a search option to this spinner ? Can any one help me with a simple example code.. (I saw some answers regarding this but they are not sufficient)..

I am new to android and i know actually this is not the correct way. but i want to add this kind of option to the spinner. When you hit a letter on the search box , list of items are displayed in the spinner relevant to that letter. Thanks a lot.

public void search(View view){

```
    cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tblRepTeritories WHERE RepCode like?", 
        new String[]{"%" + searchText.getText().toString() + "%"});


    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter1 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this, 
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, 
            cursor, 
            new String[] {"TeriCode"}, 
            new int[] {android.R.id.text1});

adapter1.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );
// get reference to our spinner
Spinner s1 = (Spinner) findViewById( R.id.spinner2 );

s1.setAdapter(adapter1);


}
```

Comment: Little bit explain it more.. And, post your code which was tried by yourself.

Comment: @SpK the code i tried is above ..thanks

Comment: Now, its working or not.

Comment: @SpK it is working.But it is not actually i want. it just give only search result.But i want this kind of thing." When you hit a letter on the search box , spinner pop up and list of items are displayed in the spinner relevant to that letter". thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you should have a look at the AutoCompleteTextView this might something that fits your needs. Check out [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-autocomplete.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use `TextWatcher` and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter:

```
searchText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tblRepTeritories WHERE RepCode like?", 
            new String[] {"%" + searchText.getText().toString() + "%"});
        adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
});
```