# How to display two Spinners with linked data?

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing, android-spinner

I want to populate the Spinner-2 on basis of Spinner-1 .

For example if I select **Newton** then Spinner-2 will show only **Force** and **Apple** and not the other values and if I select **Hiiii** only **ds** should populate on the Spinner-2. This is just an example which I am showing in the image below(all values are dynamic in the original app).*Where ever there is any value selected in spinner-1 the value with the determined tag should be populated in the spinner-2.*

[image: Image Link]

***UPDATE-3 MainActivity.java***

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, OnClickListener {

    ArrayList<String> title;
    ArrayList<String> title2;
    Button button;
    Spinner spinner;
    Spinner spinner2;
    private EditText fromDateEtxt;
    //private EditText toDateEtxt;

    private DatePickerDialog fromDatePickerDialog;
    //private DatePickerDialog toDatePickerDialog;

    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter;

    ArrayAdapter<String> from_adapter;
    ArrayAdapter<String> from_adapter2;
    Map<String, List<String>> values = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        title = new ArrayList<String>();
        title2 = new ArrayList<String>();

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this); 
        findViewsById();

        setDateTimeField();
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }


        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                parse();

                from_adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, title);
                from_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

                from_adapter2=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, title2);
                from_adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);


                spinner.setAdapter(from_adapter);
                spinner2.setAdapter(from_adapter2);


            }

            private Object from_adapter(int i) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

        });


    }



    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
            long id) {
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), ""+spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().trim(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    }

    protected void parse() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        try {

            URL url = new URL(
                    "WEB URL");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("a:AAAA");
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                Element el = (Element) nodeList.item(i);
                // get the a:W value
                String awValue = el.getElementsByTagName("a:W").item(0).getTextContent();
                // add the above value in our map  as key if it isn't present in the map, this key will 
                // have a list associated with it in which ALL the values for a:R will be stored, if 
                // the awValue key is present then you just add the new a:R value to its list 
                if (!values.containsKey(awValue)) {
                    values.put(awValue, new ArrayList<String>());
                }
                // also add the value pointed by a:R to the list associated with a:W
                String arValue = el.getElementsByTagName("a:R").item(0).getTextContent();
                values.get(awValue).add(arValue);
                Log.d("ADebugTag", "Value: " + arValue);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

                Node node = nodeList.item(i);       

                Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
                NodeList nameList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("a:W");
                Element nameElement = (Element) nameList.item(0);
                nameList = nameElement.getChildNodes();         

                NodeList websiteList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("a:R");
                Element websiteElement = (Element) websiteList.item(0);
                websiteList = websiteElement.getChildNodes();

                title.add(((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue());

            }
            NodeList nodeList2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("a:AAAA");
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList2.getLength(); i++) {

                Node node = nodeList2.item(i);       

                Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
                NodeList nameList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("a:R");
                Element nameElement = (Element) nameList.item(0);
                nameList = nameElement.getChildNodes();         
                title2.add(((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue());

            }
            Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>(title);
            title = new ArrayList<String>(set);
            // Collection<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>(months);
            Set<String> set2 = new LinkedHashSet<String>(title2);
            title2 = new ArrayList<String>(set2);
            System.out.println("list are");
            System.out.println(set);
            System.out.println("list 2 are");
            System.out.println(set2);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
        }

    }
```

**Update-4**

**I am Getting the below values IN THE LOGCAT**

```
{
Jackfruit=[Cabbage, Kesar, Amond], 
Datia=[Kalpi, Kesar, Brinjal], 
Brinjal=[Cabbage, Kesar, Amond]
}
```

So,if **Jackfruit** is selected in *spinner1* then- **Cabbage, Kesar, Amond** should diplay in *spinner2*

**The above logcat I am getting from the below code of the UPDATE-3 of the MainActivity.java**

```
NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("a:AAAAA");
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                Element el = (Element) nodeList.item(i);
                // get the a:W value
                String awValue = el.getElementsByTagName("a:W").item(0).getTextContent();
                // add the above value in our map  as key if it isn't present in the map, this key will 
                // have a list associated with it in which ALL the values for a:R will be stored, if 
                // the awValue key is present then you just add the new a:R value to its list 
                if (!values.containsKey(awValue)) {
                    values.put(awValue, new ArrayList<String>());

                }
                // also add the value pointed by a:R to the list associated with a:W
                String arValue = el.getElementsByTagName("a:R").item(0).getTextContent();
                values.get(awValue).add(arValue);

               // Log.d("ADebugTag", "Value: " + arValue);
            }
             Log.d("ADebugTag", "Value: " +  values);
```

**How should I pass the key value to spinner and if spinner key value is changed then respective values should change in spinner2**

Answer (score 1):

For the first time just fill spinner1. To do this change the parse method to return the list of main tags(`title1`),and set them to spinner.

Then use `setOnItemSelectedListener` on spinner1 and inside that , parse your XML to find items related to the selected item and fill spinner2 based on that. You can get the selected item using it's `position`. To do this write another method(or use the same method using `if` condition to say this is not main tags) that get selected item from spinner1 as input and return sub items. Then add this list to spinner2.

Finally you must have something like this:

```
   spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position) 
       {           
           title2=parse(spinner1.get(position)
          //set title2 to spinner2
       });
```

Comment: the xml data is coming from URL xml Dom parser

Comment: want to pass the hash value to spinner and if spinner data clicked to change then populate the value in spinner2 i.e Log.d("ADebugTag", "Value: " + arValue); ...where all values correctly are grouped ....so if spinner value is changed then accordingly group will be displayed in spinner2

Comment: I improved answer and explained what to do.the only thing you have to do is to change the parse method to get a string and return a list based on the input.you can use the same method for both with just using an "if" condition to differ between spinners.